# Is it Poisson or Binomial?

Tags: poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Exam Paper question I had today, I'm quite sure about some others I did but this one I'm unsure about.

A hotel has ten rooms and on average seven are occupied each night.
12 Bookings are possible on any given night.
What is the probability they will not be able to accommodate all their guests on any night?
Assumptions you made to determine this?

Any help appreciated as I'm unsure if it's Poisson or binomial?

Comment: Note the upper bound given on the number of bookings...

Comment: So given the upper bound it is a binomial? And a poisson is not applicable so you will not get the same answer?

Comment: Yes, since there is an upper bound the problem is a binomial. You'll get a different answer if you take the corresponding Poisson approximation (quite significantly different, in this case, since the upper bound is not that big). Now if you *didn't know* the upper bound, but only the average, then a Poisson would be useful. A Poisson would also give a good approximation of the binomial if the upper bound were way bigger, like 100+.

Comment: Great thank you unfortunately made a mistake on that one then thanks